# FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, This record is locked from editing

Tags: apex, trigger, exception

I have a trigger which will update a field based on some condition. On custom object whenever a record is inserted or updated the trigger will run.

So as a system admin, I am not seeing any issue. But when another user updates the record they are facing the below issue.

I know this issue is because of Approval process, but still I want to run the update.

> ```
> caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row
> 0 with id ; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, This
> record is locked from editing in &quot;Pending Approval&quot; stage.
> All approvers will be notified.: []
> ```

Trigger :

```
trigger updatefield on customObj__c (after insert,after update)
{
    List<Product__C> prodlist = [Select Id,checkbox__c,relatedCB__Lookup__c, relatedCB__Lookup__r.mLookup__c 
    FROM Product__C where relatedCB__Lookup__r.Id IN: trigger.newMap.keySet()];
    if(!prodlist.isEmpty())
    {
        for(Product__C prod :prodlist)
        {
            if(prod.relatedCB__Lookup__r.mLookup__c != null)
            {
                prod.checkbox__c = true;
            }           

        }
    }
    update prodlist;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A user with appropriate permissions can modify a record locked by an approval process.

The error you are getting is due to a **validation rule** and **not the approval process**. If it was due to the approval process locking the record you would get an Insufficient Privileges error

It may be the case that your approval process is also locking the record and if you find the validation rule and disable it you could still get an error as the process lock may now fire. But for the purpose of the error you posted, it is a validation rule causing it

Answer (score 5):

**Edit: So this answer doesn't actually answer the question and isn't really necessary. Use the accepted answer instead.**

[You can lock and unlock records with Apex](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks.htm).

First enable the feature:

> To enable this feature, from Setup, enter Process Automation Settings
>   in the Quick Find box, then click Process Automation Settings. Then,
>   select Enable record locking and unlocking in Apex.

Start by unlocking the records:

```
Approval.UnlockResult [] lrList = Approval.unlock(prodList, false);
```

Make your updates.

And then lock again:

```
Approval.LockResult[] lrList = Approval.lock(prodList, false);
```

Make sure you loop over the lock and unlock results to make sure they were successfully unlocked and locked.

Comment: Have you tested if this works when a record is in the middle of an Approval Process? Will it attempt to recall the record from an Approval Process? Seems to me like this would defeat a great deal of the purpose behind Approval Processes.

Comment: It did not recall the record in my tests. I agree that allowing arbitrary edits after approval defeats the purpose of approvals, but it might be useful for allowing certain controlled edits if necessary.

Comment: @JohnTowers - Thanks for the answer. I did not know they even added this method lol..... This method from what I read is meant to be used outside of an approval process. So you can lock records that have not been submitted for approval? Am I mistaken? If so it is a neat enhancement

Comment: They added it in Winter '16. You're correct about it's use - it's more for locking/unlocking records outside of the normal approval process.

Comment: You could also have a situation where the approval is only for a portion of the record, e.g. the approval is for the maximum amount of money that can be spent on something, but the rest of the details can still be updated.